# trigger error PLS-00103: and the error is in line 5 of code posted below

Tags: oracle, triggers

the error is in line 5 of the code posted below
I am unable to recognize the error,
However, the trigger is getting created perfectly and it is also modifying the table values as described in the code

```
create or replace trigger "SERVICE_T1"
BEFORE
insert on "SERVICE"
for each row
begin 
SELECT 'S'||to_char(SERVICE_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'fm00000000') 
INTO :new.service_id 
FROM service 
end;
/
```

Comment: Are you sure the trigger is created perfectly? There are syntax errors and you are getting a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, this line

```
FROM service
```

should be

```
FROM dual;
```

---

Demonstration:

```
SQL> create table service (service_id varchar2(50));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence service_id_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger "SERVICE_T1"
  2    BEFORE insert on "SERVICE"
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    SELECT 'S'||to_char(SERVICE_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'fm00000000')
  6    INTO :new.service_id
  7    FROM dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into service values ('A');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From service;

SERVICE_ID
--------------------------------------------------
S00000001

SQL>
```

---

Or, even better, to avoid `select` completely:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger "SERVICE_T1"
  2    BEFORE insert on "SERVICE"
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.service_id := 'S'||to_char(SERVICE_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'fm00000000');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you @littlefoot it worked !!

P.S -  I am a big fan of Lie to Me